# Соединение WCF Channel не работает при запуске из сервиса

Tags: c#, wcf, windows-service

Всем привет!

Я создаю такое соединение:

```
        EndpointAddress address = new EndpointAddress("https://xxx.xxx.ru/b2bJSON.asmx");
        BasicHttpBinding binding = new BasicHttpBinding(BasicHttpSecurityMode.Transport);
        binding.MaxBufferSize = 64000000;
        binding.MaxReceivedMessageSize = 64000000;
        binding.ReceiveTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 10, 0);
        binding.SendTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 10, 0);

        ChannelFactory<B2BJSONSoap> factory = new ChannelFactory<B2BJSONSoap>(binding, address);
        factory.Credentials.UserName.UserName = userName;
        factory.Credentials.UserName.Password = pw;
        B2BJSONSoap channel = factory.CreateChannel();
```

Запросы через это соединение нормально отрабатывают при прямом запуске, при запуске юнит тестов из другого проекта тоже.

Для того, чтобы обойти прокси в App.config, пришлось прописать это:

```html
<configuration>
  <system.net>
    <defaultProxy enabled="false" useDefaultCredentials="false">
      <proxy />
    </defaultProxy>
  </system.net>
</configuration>
```

Я создал проект Windows Service, который запускает проект, в котором соединение, запросы и все остальное. И при запуске через сервис, валится такое исключение:

```html
System.ServiceModel.EndpointNotFoundException: Прослушивание на https://xxx.xxx.ru/b2bJSON.asmx не выполняла ни одна конечная точка, которая могла бы принять сообщение. Среди прочих причин это могло быть вызвано неправильным адресом или действием SOAP. Подробнее см. в описании InnerException (если имеется). ---> System.Net.WebException: Невозможно соединиться с удаленным сервером ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: Попытка установить соединение была безуспешной, т.к. от другого компьютера за требуемое время не получен нужный отклик, или было разорвано уже установленное соединение из-за неверного отклика уже подключенного компьютера xxx:443
   в System.Net.Sockets.Socket.DoConnect(EndPoint endPointSnapshot, SocketAddress socketAddress)
   в System.Net.ServicePoint.ConnectSocketInternal(Boolean connectFailure, Socket s4, Socket s6, Socket& socket, IPAddress& address, ConnectSocketState state, IAsyncResult asyncResult, Exception& exception)
   --- Конец трассировки внутреннего стека исключений ---
   в System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetRequestStream(TransportContext& context)
   в System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()
   в System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpOutput.WebRequestHttpOutput.GetOutputStream()
   --- Конец трассировки внутреннего стека исключений ---
```

В чем причина появления этого исключения тут? При том, что без сервиса код отлично работает.

Comment: Это весь файл `App.config` ?

Comment: В проекте с сервисом - да. В основном проекте свой файл, он больше, там загружены адреса и bindings из service references, которые я добавил. В нем тоже прописано про прокси.

Comment: "В проекте с сервисом" - здесь сервис - это win сервис клиент, правильно я понимаю?

Comment: Да, windows service

Answer (score 0):

Дело было в настройках локальной сети. LocalService просто не проходил прокси.
Установщик сервиса написал так:

```
[RunInstaller(true)]
public class ProjectInstaller : Installer
{
    private ServiceProcessInstaller process;
    private ServiceInstaller service;

    public ProjectInstaller()
    {
        process = new ServiceProcessInstaller();
        process.Account = ServiceAccount.User;
        service = new ServiceInstaller();
        service.ServiceName = "WebServiceDownload";
        Installers.Add(process);
        Installers.Add(service);
    }
}
```

При установке запрашивает логин и пароль, указал юзера из сети, работает.

Comment: Вы же писали что обошли прокси? Как так вышло, что обойденный прокси вас не пускал?

Comment: Наверно не обошел, а скорее написал настройку для того, чтобы пройти прокси. Пользователь, зарегистрированный в сети проходит прокси, а локальная/сетевая служба/система - нет.